# What is the correct way to create a data context for a console app in EWL?

Tags: c#, console-application, worker, enterprise-web-library

Is this the right way to do a console application's data context?

```
AppTools
     .Init("App's daily operations", 
           false,
           new GlobalLogic(),
           () => new DataAccessState(cn => cn.Open()));
```

If not, then how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about a server-side console app, you don't even need to call `AppTools.Init`. Here's the correct way:

1. In your console project, create a class file called `Program.cs`.
2. In the file, your class should look like this:

   ```
   partial class Program {
     static partial void initGlobalLogic( ref SystemLogic globalLogic ) {
       globalLogic = new YourGlobalLogicClass();
     }

     static partial void ewlMain( string[] args ) {
       DataAccessState.Current.PrimaryDatabaseConnection.ExecuteWithConnectionOpen( () => {
         // Your code goes here.
         // Skip the ExecuteWithConnectionOpen call if you don't need the database.
       }
     }
   }
   ```